# Add content -> taxonomy autocomplete input field size

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, ajax

My content type has a taxonomy auto-complete field.
My problem is that some content requires like 10-20 taxonomy terms where my input field for it is way to small.

I don't see in my 'manage fields' settings where I can define this length.

Comment: Do you have any programming skills? can you write a custom module?

Comment: Can't you use css to make it larger?

Comment: Yes I am familiar with creating modules. I already thought of creating a preprocessor for this, but was trying to figure out if this was a standard settings in drupal like the textarea properties.

Comment: You can set the width of the element simply using css. You don't have to write any custom module.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Entity Reference module](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference); it allows the size of the autocomplete input field to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw in a similar question this info :
https://www.drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe "This is an enhanced autocomplete element, that uses the JQuery UI autocomplete. It will also implement a widget for taxonomy."